# How to expand the class "BinaryFileResponse" in dir "vendor" Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

It is necessary to expand the method of "**sendContent**", namely, add a method to delete (**deleteDirAfterSend**) the directory after downloading the file.

Class: *Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;* 
Modify Method: *sendContent();*

How to implement this correctly?

```
protected $deleteDir = null;

/**
 * Sends the file.
 *
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function sendContent()
{
    if (!$this->isSuccessful()) {
        return parent::sendContent();
    }

    if (0 === $this->maxlen) {
        return $this;
    }

    $out = fopen('php://output', 'wb');
    $file = fopen($this->file->getPathname(), 'rb');

    stream_copy_to_stream($file, $out, $this->maxlen, $this->offset);

    fclose($out);
    fclose($file);

    if ($this->deleteFileAfterSend && file_exists($this->file->getPathname())) {
        unlink($this->file->getPathname());
    }

    if ($this->deleteDirAfterSend && file_exists($this->deleteDir)) {
        rmdir($this->deleteDir);
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * If this is set to true, the file will be unlinked after the request is send
 * Note: If the X-Sendfile header is used, the deleteDirAfterSend setting will not be used.
 *
 * @param bool $shouldDelete
 *
 * @param null $dir
 * @return $this
 */
public function deleteDirAfterSend($shouldDelete = true, $dir = null)
{
    $this->deleteDirAfterSend = $shouldDelete;
    $this->deleteDir = $dir;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow, it's unclear what you're asking, are you trying to override vendor files? if so then don't! and never do, all of your changes within that directory would be lost on composer update or install

Comment: It's better to not do anything after the response has been given. Maybe consider cleaning up by dispatching a cleanup job and running a queue every so often?

Comment: I wanted to know how to get around the fact that all changes in the vendor catalog will fly into the furnace. Thank.

Comment: You don't need to mess up the original class, you can use events and observers for this kind of things: https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/events.